# Replacing a leading wildcard query in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have an application that searches the index for matching barcodes with an unknown prefix that may or may not exist. Currently the application is using a leading wildcard in a **WildcardQuery** to account for the prefix, however, this is obviously causing *performance* issues. I've looked into using the ReverseStringFilter, but it uses a TokenStream and I'm not sure how I'd use it in this situation.

Here is a very basic example of how this is currently implemented, but should give you a good idea of what's going on:

```
BooleanQuery allBCQueries;
BooleanQuery bcQuery;
for( barcode : barcodeList){
  bcQuery.add( new WildcardQuery( new Term('barcode', "*" + barcode)), Occur.Must);
  allBCQueries.add(bcQuery, Occur.should);
}
BooleanQuery result;
result.add(allBCQueries, Occur.Must);
```

Then result is used to search the index.

Is there a way to eliminate the leading wildcard to improve performance?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get what's the problem with ReverseStringFilter?

Comment: The problem would be my lack of understanding how ReverseStringFilter would be used in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comments - idea would be to use [ReverseStringFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/reverse/ReverseStringFilter.html) which is effectively reverting the tokens and instead of barcode "123123" would create token "321321". This means, that those queries with unexpected prefix could be rewritten.

Instead of `barcode:*123` we could use query `barcode:123*` which would be much more effective.

Adding document with a custom TokenStream on field is pretty easy:

```
final Tokenizer token = new KeywordTokenizer();
Document doc = new Document();
token.setReader(new StringReader(value));
doc.add(new TextField("barcode", value, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("reverse-barcode", new ReverseStringFilter(token)));
```

This way we are applying keyword tokenizer (e.g. no tokenizer) + reverse string filter, while keeping the original value

I've did some testing with 1 mln documents filled with random barcodes (e.g. longs in my case) and reverse approach got approximately **30%** advantage, while providing exactly the same number of results.

Full example could be found [there](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene7/src/main/java/BarcodeReverseQuery.java)